# Checking active ports

Tags: command-line, networking

I have a specific port number with me and  want to check if it is active or not. I tried:

```
netstat -an | grep $portnum
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can scan for open ports with nmap

```
nmap {ip addr}
```

Like so:

```
nmap 192.168.0.1
```

The output should be something like this:

```
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE

8080/tcp  open  http

9020/tcp open  iss-realsecure
```

Answer (score 0):

To *test* for a specific port on your machine you can use `nmap` with your own IP (obtained by `hostname -I`) and `grep` for the port number:

```bsh
portnum=22
ip=$(hostname -I)
nmap $ip | grep -Eq ^$portnum/ && echo yes || echo no
```

or with `if`:

```bsh
if nmap $ip | grep -Eq ^$portnum/; then
  echo yes
else
  echo no
fi
```